# ThreadPoolExecutor logging? (python)

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

I have some code that looks like

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    for function in functions:
        executor.submit(function)
```

How would I log which function is currently being handled by the executor? I may or may not have the capability to log from within the functions - would want the executor itself to log something like

```
print "handling process {i}".format(i=current_process)
```

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is a little old but I stumbled across the questions and thought I would put an answer in. I just used a wrapper that can reference an instance of a logger prior to calling the function:

```
import logging
import os
import concurrent.futures


logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/log.txt'), level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger("MyLogger")


def logging_wrapper(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("Func name: {0}".format(func.__name__))
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


def a():
    print('a ran')


def b():
    print('b ran')


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    for func in [a, b]:
        executor.submit(logging_wrapper(func))
```